# Adding intent type to android flutter manifest leads to missing app icon in home screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I followed the example code mentioned here [android intents flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter) 
It worked successfully but it leads to missing the app icon in the Android home screen.
also, I noticed that the app icon depends on the following line in the manifest file.

```
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

removing the above line makes the app icon available on the home screen. but android intent functions are not working.
I can't figure out why is it.
Here is a part of manifest file.

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="flutterappjava"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        .................
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I hope it's a good solution.
I separated the action.send intent to a different java file and assigned it to a different activity in the manifest file.

```
<application
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
android:label="flutterappjava"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
    .................
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
 <activity android:name=".tempAct">
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
 </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</activity>
```

Comment: but flutter is a single activity